# select an entire word from comma seperated sentence

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a node js code that has a return value from my DB and is in comma separated and the result is as below.

```
const carsList = "Audi, Ford Ikon, Mercedes Benz";
var carType = "Ford";
if (carsList.toLowerCase().indexOf(carType.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
    console.log(carType + " is the car");
}
```

here I'm able to get the output as `Ford is the car`.

But I want it as below.

`Ford Ikon is the car`.

in simple words, if I say `Mercedes` or `Benz`, it should print `Mercedes Benz is the car`. Similarly, If I say `Ford` or `Ikon`, it should print `Ford Ikon is the car`.

In my code I'm able to check, but not able to get he entire word. please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Create an array by splitting the string by comma, and then use the trimmed values in that array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this:

```
const carsList = "Audi, Ford Ikon, Mercedes Benz";
const cars = carsList.split(',');
let carType = 'Ford';
let carFound = cars.filter(car => car.includes(carType));
if (carFound.length) {
console.log(carFound[0] + " is the car");
}
```

Explanation:

1. split the array on the basis of comma.
2. use the array's filter function to filter the car name.
3. if any matching value is found then the length will be greater than 0 and the output will be printed on the console.

right now, the assumption is that only 1 entry will exist therefore carFound[0] is used on the console.log. this can easily be converted into a for loop in case there are multiple cars found in the filter function.

Comment: Also you can split by comma and space `const cars = carsList.split(', ');` to avoid trailing space in case of Ford and Mercedes.

Comment: that is correct yes you can get rid of the extra space before Ford and Mercedes.

but overall, i do not think it would matter with this specific problem as includes would work both with and without spaces.

good catch though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const cars = "Audi, Ford Ikon, Mercedes Benz";
var carsArray = cars.split(',');

const manufacturerName = 'Ford';
searchForCar(manufacturerName,carsArray);

const modelName = 'Ikon';
searchForCar(modelName,carsArray);

function searchForCar(needle,haystack){
  for(var i =0;i<haystack.length;i++){
    if(haystack[i].indexOf(needle) !== -1){
      console.log(haystack[i].trim() + " is the car");
      return;
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the string into an array:

```
const cars = "Audi, Ford Ikon, Mercedes Benz";
var carsArray = cars.split(",");
var carType = "Ford";
```

Then iterate through the list to check if the keyword is contained in any of the elements:

```
for (var make in carsArray):
    if (make.toLowerCase().includes(carType.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log(carType + " is the car");
    }   
}
```